# How to integrate the area under a curve multiplied by another variable?

Tags: calculus

I am basically trying to integrate something like the following:
[drawing of integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A84bu.jpg)

$$ \int_0^{5.1} \mathrm{data} * (t) \,\mathrm{d}t $$

So I have a data set that I need to get the area underneath the curve for. I figured out how to do this using various methods, but I cannot find a way online that tells me how to deal with it when there is an additional variable multiplied by it within the integrand. Also, this would be a definite integral since I know the bounds of the integral and all of the data points. I am not sure if I am using the correct terminology since I haven't taken math in awhile, but any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you indicate your method of computing $\int_0^{5.1} \mathrm{data}(t) \,\mathrm{d}t$?  Then we can more usefully describe how to modify that method to account for the additional factor of "$t$".

Comment: That integral can be input as "\$\$  \int_0^{5.1} \mathrm{data}(t) \,\mathrm{d}t  \$\$".

Comment: I am using python to compute the area under the data points using either the trapezoid method or Simpson's method. I have gotten both to work.

Comment: Is the data set continuous or discrete?

Comment: The data is discrete, I have the x and y values for every data point.

Answer (score 0):

At present your data points are $y_i=g(t_i)$. All you need to do is change your data points to $y_i=f(t_i)g(t_i)$ where $f(t_i)$ is the value of the variable at the same $t$ values used for your data points $g(t_i)$ . Then apply the same numerical method of integration as before.